# Axes3D plot taking a lot of time and using a lot of RAM

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I have the following code to create a 3D plot of a Bivariate Gaussian Distribution:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

class Data(object):
    data = None
    columns = 0
    rows = 0

    def __init__(self, path='file.txt'):
        self.data = np.loadtxt(path, delimiter=' ', dtype='float32')
        self.rows, self.columns = self.data.shape

    def _pdf(self, x, mu, cov):
        part1 = 1 / ( ((2* np.pi)**(len(mu)/2)) * (np.linalg.det(cov)**(1/2)) )
        part2 = (-1/2) * ((x-mu).T.dot(np.linalg.inv(cov))).dot((x-mu))
        return float(part1 * np.exp(part2))

    def compute_Z(self):
        mu  = np.array([[2.99413181],[3.05209659]], dtype="float")
        cov = np.array([[1.01023423, 0.02719138], [0.02719138, 2.93782296]], dtype="float")
        Z = []
        for i, j in zip(X, Y):
            x = np.array([i,j]).reshape(2,1)
            Z.append(self._pdf(x, mu, cov))
        return np.array(Z)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = Data()
    X = data.data[:, 0]
    Y = data.data[:, 1]
    Z = data.compute_Z()

    X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, color='0.9', alpha=0.9, linewidth=1)
    plt.show()
```

But this is taking a lot of time and also using a lot of RAM. Is there some way to reduce it? Or there is a better method to create this plot?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

matplotlib 3D plotting isn't very good for large amount of data.

You can use `mayavi`, which has very similar interface using `mlab`.

```py
from mayavi import mlab

mlab.figure()
mlab.surf(X, Y, Z)
mlab.show()
```